# How do I link a DLL to a Java project in VSCode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, dll, native, libraries

I'm using **LWJGL** which has native libraries for my project to use. My question is how do I add native libraries to a Java project in **VSCode**? Also, when I created the project I selected the *"no build tools"* option if that's helpful.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't maven or gradle in your project, choosing no build tools is okay. Then turn to **JAVA PROJECTS**, find `Referenced Libraries` and click `+` to add local jars:

[image]

**[UPDATE]**

To add ddl, add the following in `launch.json`:

```
"vmArgs": "-Djava.library.path=\"path/to/library\""
```

Comment: when I use that it only references jar files but I want to use DLL

Comment: @Hans. I've updated my answer, please have a try